# Algorithm to find direction between two keys on the num pad?

Tags: puzzle

Given the following direction enum:

```
typedef enum {
    DirectionNorth = 0,
    DirectionNorthEast,
    DirectionEast,
    DirectionSouthEast,
    DirectionSouth,
    DirectionSouthWest,
    DirectionWest,
    DirectionNorthWest
} Direction;
```

And number matrix similar to the numeric pad:

```
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

How would you write a function to return the direction between adjacent numbers from the matrix? Say:

```
1, 2 => DirectionEast
2, 1 => DirectionWest
4, 8 => DirectionNorthEast
1, 7 => undef
```

You may change the numeric values of the enum if you want to. Readable solutions preferred. (Not a homework, just an algorithm for an app I am working on. I have a working version, but I’m interested in more elegant takes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int direction_code(int a, int b)
{
    assert(a >= 1 && a <= 9 && b >= 1 && b <= 9);
    int ax = (a - 1) % 3, ay = (a - 1) / 3,
        bx = (b - 1) % 3, by = (b - 1) / 3,
        deltax = bx - ax, deltay = by - ay;
    if (abs(deltax) < 2 && abs(deltay) < 2)
        return 1 + (deltay + 1)*3 + (deltax + 1);
    return 5;
}
```

resulting codes are

```
1 south-west
2 south
3 south-east
4 west
5 invalid
6 east
7 north-west
8 north
9 north-east
```

Comment: Great answer! I would have added one to the result, so that 5 becames invalid. That way I can think of the result as a direction from the center of the numpad.

Answer (score 3):

I would redefine the values in the enum so that North, South, East and West take a different bit each.

```
typedef enum {
    undef = 0,
    DirectionNorth = 1,
    DirectionEast = 2,
    DirectionSouth = 4,
    DirectionWest = 8,
    DirectionNorthEast = DirectionNorth | DirectionEast,
    DirectionSouthEast = DirectionSouth | DirectionEast,
    DirectionNorthWest = DirectionNorth | DirectionWest,
    DirectionSouthWest = DirectionSouth | DirectionWest
} Direction;
```

With those new values:

```
int ax = ( a - 1 ) % 3, ay = ( a - 1 ) / 3;
int bx = ( b - 1 ) % 3, by = ( b - 1 ) / 3;

int diffx = std::abs( ax - bx );
int diffy = std::abs( ay - by );

int result = undef;
if( diffx <= 1 && diffy <= 1 )
{
    result |= ( bx == ax - 1 ) ? DirectionWest : 0;
    result |= ( bx == ax + 1 ) ? DirectionEast : 0;
    result |= ( by == ay - 1 ) ? DirectionSouth : 0;
    result |= ( by == ay + 1 ) ? DirectionNorth : 0;
}
return static_cast< Direction >( result );
```

**Update:** Finally, I think its correct now.

Comment: How well that ever set more than one bit, since only exactly one of those `y==` equalities can be true, for a given `x`?

Comment: I believe so now (Had been busy posting an answer with corrected equalities)

Comment: I thought 0-based grid, integral mod and div were sufficient. What edge case did you find that added the requirement for the `diff` variables?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: 1, 7 is supposed to return `undef`, if it weren't for the `diff` variables it would have returned North.

Comment: `ay` = 0/3 = 0. `by` = 6/3 = 2. By my math, `by` != `ay + 1`. How does `North` get set?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Was it 1, 6 then? Yep, sorry I gave you the wrong example.

Answer (score 0):

With this matrix of numbers the following holds true:
1) a difference of 1 (+ve or -ve) always implies that the direction is either east or west.
2) similary, a difference of 3 for direction north or south.
3) a difference of 4 north east or south west.
4) a difference of 2 north west or south east.